# Param user_id is not a valid Instagram User ID for HTTP GET

Tags: oauth, instagram-api, hashtag, userid

I am using the Instagram API and I'm having some small roadblocks. I already got my Access Token working on the Graph API but the user_id I'm feeding it seems to not be working, I'm retrieving the ID from [Otzberg](http://otzberg.net/iguserid/) using the app-linked Instagram account's username, but I'm not sure it's the right one.

Here's the query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ig_hashtag_search?user_id={USER_ID}&q={HASHTAG}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

1. You had get **legacy instagram user id** from Otzberg. This user id had work with old instagram API. When you call your endpoint with this user id you should get message : `Param user_id is not a valid Instagram User ID` .
2. For use ig_hashtag_search you should get permission for `Instagram Public Content Access`
3. You should use [IG User#id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user) with this endpoint. You can search user id from  [business-discovery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery/)(`GET /{ig-user-id}/business_discovery`).

**P.S.** new ig-user-id - usually it 17+/- numbers.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the fast response.

I'm likely missing something but I fail to understand how I would retrieve my ig-user-id with a query that requires my ig-user-id.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me - fetch your id. Then [https://graph.facebook.com/{your-id}?fields=instagram_business_account](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/page/)- and fetch your business_account_id. Here example response from docs ```{
  "instagram_business_account": {
    "id": "17841405822304914"
  },
  "id": "134895793791914"
}.id```. You should use your `instagram_business_account.id`  for `ig_hashtag_search `

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me says "error": {
"message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",

Answer (score 0):

On a browser on which you are authenticated on the good account go the page : https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: i tried this but found it to give the same user_id as the one returned by Otzberg